# Chrome keeps snapping on Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, browser

I have to load a single page multiple times until I don't get the "Aw,Snap!" error or the "This site can't be reached" page(which averages to about three times per page). The connection is fine, seems to be an issue with the PC.

I've tried uninstalling and deleting all Chrome data, and reinstalling but the problem still persists. I didn't really use Firefox before this, and while it doesn't snap, it crashes often. I have deleted whatever 'junk' software might have been causing this, and right now I only have a few essential programs installed, and the problem is still very much there.

How do I go about troubleshooting and fixing this? My machine hardware is enough to run these smoothly with multiple tabs open, because it did so a few months ago.

Worth mentioning is that it has this problem more on certain sides like youtube, but for superuser, for example it often loads the first time.

Comment: Check for spyware and virusses. They're likely the cause. Sounds like something inserted a proxy server to collect data from you.

Comment: @LPChip Checked, nothing. I only have a couple of other things installed and the rest of my PC has been wiped clean.

Comment: Does it have the same problem in Firefox or Opera?

Comment: @Mokubai I didn't try Opera, but Firefox is extremely slow and just keeps hanging/crashing. No 'Aw, Snap!' error though, it does load the first time.